# Fastest way to cut an array into two arrays at a particular index

Tags: java, performance, array

Suppose I have the array:

```
double[] arrayToCut = new double[100];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i) {
    arrayToCut[i] = Math.random();
}
```

My objective is to end up with two arrays, `firstArray` and `secondArray`. `firstArray` is equal to (for example);

```
double[] firstArray = new double[50];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; ++i) {
    firstArray[i] = arrayToCut[i];
}
```

and `secondArray` is defined analogously (taking values from `arrayToCut` from `50` to `99` index).

However, this is linear time complexity and I want to cut gigantic arrays over 1 million in length. How can I speed up the above code (reduce computational overhead in any way for large arrays, whether by time complexity reduction or some other approach)?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100371/grabbing-a-segment-of-an-array-in-java

Comment: And here I was hoping it was C and would be a simple pointer question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can use `copyOfRange(double[] original, int from, int to)` from `java.util.Arrays`. @Rolfl said, and I quote : *It is recommended practice to use Arrays.copyOf instead of System.arraycopy().*

If you need to cut up the million+ array for parallel processing, then I would suggest you chunk the data while reading it, this should save you a processing step.

---

Edit: Internally, `Arrays.copyOf()` uses `System.arraycopy()` to do the hard work of duplicating the Array data in the new copy, and it will make your code look like this simple 1-liner:

```
double[] firstArray = Arrays.copyOf(arrayToCut, 50);
double[] secondArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayToCut, 50, 100);
```

While using `System.arraycopy()` may seem like the fastest alternative, whenever you copy an array you have to:

- first create the destination for the data to be copied to. This step requires initializing all the destination array points to their initialization values, which is a linear operation, but done in native code, so is fast.
- then call the System.arraycopy() for the actual data re-write.

There are many ways that people may want to do this operation, and the various `Arrays.copy*()` methods are designed to make the relatively mundane, yet still rather complicated and bug-prone process a lot simpler, and less buggy.

[Whenever you have a use case where you are copying data from one array to a **new** array, you should by default use the `Arrays.copy*()` methods.](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3680241/Copying-Arrays-in-Java-6.htm) Only when you have a use case where you are overwriting data in to an existing array (or relocating data inside an array) should you use `System.arraycopy()`. As for the performance aspect, it appears that the [performance of most native mechanisms are similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12157504/1305253).

Arrays.copy* methods lead to better, more maintainable, and less buggy code, and, there is essentially no performance penalty because it is just doing the work you were going to do anyway.

Comment: This will actually call System.arrayCopy, as can be seen [in the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.copyOfRange%28double%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29)

Comment: Right your are!

Comment: +1 because 10 is so much nicer than 9, and 11 silver / 77 bronze is so much better than 11 silver / 76 bronze ;)

Answer (score 6):

The method [System.arrayCopy(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) invokes the native JIT implementation code for copying arrays and [is the fastest alternative for large arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526907/is-javas-system-arraycopy-efficient-for-small-arrays).

In the end though, `Arrays.copyOfRange` is actually calling `System.arrayCopy`.